# How to programmatically create a content type in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I think the question is self-explanatory.

For example i need a content type named "person" with 2 fields (name, age).

I tried googling etc, but although there are many references on "drupal 7 add content type programmatically", I can find no references for Drupal 8.

I was able to create content types in Drupal 7, but it seems things have changed a little bit.

Any references (if not full code) are welcome.

Comment: Pro tip: go [here](https://www.drupal.org/list-changes/drupal), and search for the name of the function you would use to do the same thing in D7 (in this case "node_type_save", which yields: https://www.drupal.org/node/2029519). It's not exhaustive, but the big ticket items are all covered in the change records

Answer (score 0):

I set up a Drupal 8 back-end with the views REST API enabled, and created a simple front-end with jQuery. The jQuery would post a new content type to a php page that would interact with the REST API. Here's the code I used to create the node array and send it to the site:

```
$node = [
    '_links' => [
        'type' => ['href' => 'http://<SITE URL>/rest/type/node/page']
    ],
    'title' => [
        0 => ['value' => "New Node Title"]
    ]
];

$data = json_encode($node);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_URL => '<SITE URL>/entity/node',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ['Content-type: application/hal+json'],
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => '<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>',
]);

echo curl_exec($ch);
```

The difficult part is building the node array structure correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As with anything, there are several ways to skin this cat.

- Use [Configuration Defaults](https://www.drupal.org/node/2087879) to include your content type and fields. [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) is the easiest way to do that. [Dribbit.eu](http://dribbit.eu/drupal-8/create-a-content-type-programatically-drupal-8) also has an example.
- Create new (edit old) configuration entities. Most of the time this has to do with *updating* content types... like Basic Page or Article. An example is here on [D.O](https://www.drupal.org/node/2535476)

Answer (score 0):

Just create the content type using a Drupal-installation (an empty test one will do). To make life easy use some distinct text in the machine-names. Example: suppose mkk is your module name, make the machine-name for your content-type mkk_person, field machine-name field_mkk_person_name.
Once done, go to the directory of the (test) installation and run in a terminal "drush -y cex"). In the directory .../sync (it will show the complete name) you will find files with mkk in their name.  Copy those files in the directory ...modules/mkk/config/install and you're done.

You can still change the content types and redo the operation, but because there are uuid 's (look in the files) all over the place, I assume that you have to keep those uuid's intact.  So, reuse the test-machine or install the module first in a new one.